# Replace faulty harddrive in Proliant DL180 G6

Tags: hotswap, hp-proliant

I have a Proliant DL180 G6 server with a Smart Array P410 controller. One of the hard drives lights amber, but the server is still running perfect. It is running RAID5 or 6 (don't remember).

Now, can I just buy a new hard drive and take the faulty out and put the new in while the server is running, and will it automatically rebuild? No need for entering the RAID configuration ?

/Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just hot-swap the drives. The p410 should automatically start the rebuild the array. During the rebuild, performance will be degraded until the rebuild is complete. Assuming RAID5, if a second drive fails during the rebuild, you will most likely be restoring from backups.

Answer (score 5):

> It is running RAID5 or 6 (dont remember)

You might want to confirm that before you go any further.

> Now, can I just buy a new harddrive and take the faulty out and put
>   the new in while the server is running, and will it automaticlly
>   rebuild? No need for entering the RAID configuration?

Use the Array Configuration Utility to look at the array health and change its options. For example setting the rebuild priority to high. Quoth the manual: `The array will begin to rebuild as soon as the drive is spun-up and tested.` However, I would strongly suggest being thoroughly versed with the [HP Recommended SMART Array Rebuilding/Restoring Techniques manual](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/c-products/servers/proliantstorage/drivers-enclosures/hp_hard_drive_replacement.pdf) before doing anything.

In fact, check [all the manuals for the P410](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/pdfDisplay/Download_emr_na-c00729544-15?docId=emr_na-c00729544&locale=en_US&hasAccess=false).

Comment: I will check whenever it is running RAID5 or 6, but I think it is level 6, because it is runnung on 5x 500 GB with 2TB of available space.

Comment: 5x500GB drives with 2TB usable is RAID5

Comment: HP sometimes reported issues if firmware on the drives was different.  Worth checking HP support around this. As @WesleyDavid
 notes, the config utility is critical as well